# spacemacs: org-capture generates point with unexpected highlight

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, org-capture

In spacemacs, when I use `org-capture` to insert in an existing `.org` file with a template, I get an orange highlight that I don't expect, and I don't know what it means:

[image]

In the image the 2021/07/16 point was typed manually, the 2021/07/19 was added by `org-capture`. I'd like the orange highlight on that point to go away.

Update: this seems to go away after closing the buffer and reopening it. I'd still like to know more about what this highlighted state is.